# how is synchonous code associated with event loop in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, event-handling

The [node js docs](https://github.com/nodejs/nodejs.org/blob/master/locale/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick.md) about event loop workflow is pretty confusing, i have couple of questions for which havent got sturdy answers after going through numerous JSconf talks and blogs. Hopefully someone will help me.

1. Statement: Event loop runs on single thread and single most place where all node js code executes (lets not discuss about libruv thread pool)
   Question: how does event loop handle the synchronous code along with aync code in event loop?
   Is there any involvement of poll phase watcher_queue in this ? If not, which phase does synchronous code go into.
2. Statement: Poll phase has all incoming requests handled by it.

   Question: Does all requests (not interested in callbacks) go to poll phase watcher_queue and then it decides which phase to push this request into OR poll phase itself will execute the request?

**If you are not comfortable with the name watcher_queue, consider it a poll phase's queue.
**Internet has very vague opinion about event loop so please be very sure